# Hide play button overlay on HTML5 video on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

We want a video to autoplay but the play button overlay remains on the video regardless if we use the autoplay attribute or if we remove the autoplay attribute and play the video using Javascript on page load. I have tried dozens of different solutions presented as answers to similar questions and in blog posts about this, nothing is working. No matter what there is always a play button overlay visible on the video.

[image]

Here is our current code:

```
<video class="js-banner-video is-paused" muted playsinline loop id="holiday-video">
    <source src="<?php echo $banner_video['url'] ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

```
    /* Banner video */
    let touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
    const video = document.querySelector('.js-banner-video');

    if (document.documentElement.contains(video)) {
      video.addEventListener(touchEvent, videoPlayPause);
      video.play();
    }

    function videoPlayPause() {
      if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
      } else {
        video.pause();
      }
    }
```

I have tried 10 different variations of CSS to hide the shadow dom element, none of them seem to work.

I've also tried:

```
video.removeAttribute('controls');
```

and

```
video.focus();
```

But the play button overlay never goes away. I'm testing in Safari, Chrome and Firefox on iOS. I noted many answers saying this is because iOS disables autoplay in low power mode - but my device is not in low power mode.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try some this, but i think this help you only for IOS not for Android but i try found more ways now try this, add on your `css file`

```
 video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button {
   display: none;
 }

*::-webkit-media-controls-panel {

  display: none!important;

  -webkit-appearance: none;

}

*::--webkit-media-controls-play-button {

  display: none!important;

  -webkit-appearance: none;

}

*::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {

  display: none!important;

  -webkit-appearance: none;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have these in place now and the play button overlay is still visible unfortunately.